# Trying to retrieve yahoo weather using jquery / php / xml

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yahoo-api

Whats wrong with this function?

```
function yahooWeather(){
    var loadPage = 'yahooweather.php?p='+ $("#myCity").val();
    $("#yahoo").html('<img src="loading.gif" align="absmiddle">');
    $("#yahoo").load(loadPage);
}
```

Is there another way to write this function.  Im unsure if its able to read the .val required, tho i know it is set as i used it in a previous function to test that it was being set, so im thinking its maybe my load call.

http://www.wetterkanal.tv/

This is the page.  This function once called by clicking the button, should get the value set by the "select city" option then load the weather in a div below. I have set the css to this div as green so i know it loads.  I also know that my php script works as if i test it by going to the following:

http://wetterkanal.tv/yahooweather.php?p=ASXX0001

it pulls the weather in correctly.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `button` element will reload the page when the button is clicked.

You need to change your `onclick` attribute to `onclick="yahooWeather(); return false;`".