# Finding non-closed XML nodes (Yahoo weather)

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, yahoo, weather

I'm trying to use Javascript to pull data from Yahoo Weather (eg http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=9807&u=c).

I've looked at other threads including [Trying to pull in elements from Yahoo Weather XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480933/trying-to-pull-in-elements-from-yahoo-weather-xml) and [Trying to retrieve yahoo weather using jquery / php / xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172836/trying-to-retrieve-yahoo-weather-using-jquery-php-xml) and [Parsing XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083565/parsing-xml-namespaces)

I've set up a proxy on my server so Ajax can grab the file, and it opens up fine (eg I can write the documentElement). However, I'm having problems grabbing the tags such as

```
<yweather:condition text="Mostly Cloudy" code="28" temp="5" date="Mon, 06 Feb 2012 10:00 am PST"/>
```

I think it's because it's not a close tag like

```
<ttl>60</ttl>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Using Javascript
Thanks

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlDoc, "text/xml");

alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ttl")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); //works
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:location")[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("city")); //doesn't
```

Comment: Also, that tag/element is closed. That's what the solidus (`/` at the end of the tag does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read that 'Parsing XML Namespaces' answer again.

The element you're looking for has a namespace, so you need to use `getElementsByTagNameNS`.